# Changing the coordinate value of a Pointz object with python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, coordinates, point

How can I change the X,Y or Z value of a Pointz feature with python in QGIS?
I am trying to change the Z values of Pointz with a python plugin.   I am first trying to pass the selected feature to a variable in the program.  I can get to the geometry in the program and on the console.

```
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()[0]
geom = selection.geometry()
print(geom)
<QgsGeometry: PointZ (26141648.89000000059604645 642064.42000000004190952 
767.54999999999995453)>
```

Then I get stuck trying to get the Z coordinates out.   I have tried the geom.z() and geom.id() and I get errors. geom.asPoint()[1] does give me the X and Y values but not the Z.   Is there a way to get and change the "Z"

```
<QgsGeometry: PointZ (26141648.89000000059604645 642064.42000000004190952 
767.54999999999995453)>
geom.x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'x'
```

***UPDATE***

This is similar to what I ended up with.   The lines with wkt in them generate the geometry from "well known text".   This did work but I took it out for the better .setX() method.  You would have to change the feature.setGeometry(***geom***) to feature.setGeometry(***new_pnt***) to use that method.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
    print(layer)
    all_features = layer.getFeatures()
    layer.startEditing()
    for feature in all_features:
        print(feature['NUMBER'])
        if feature['NUMBER'] == '1003':
            print('found it ********\n  ')
            feature['SUMPDIST'] = '18.55'
            geom = feature.geometry()
            print(geom)
            new_feat = QgsFeature()
            point1 = QgsPoint(26132109.5, 644411.8, 940.600)

            #new_pnt = QgsGeometry.fromWkt("POINTZ(26132109.5 644411.8 940.48)")
            wkt = "POINTZ(" + str(point1.x()) + " " + str(point1.y()) + " " + str(point1.z()) +")"
            new_pnt = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt) #This well known text works also But I like the .setX, .setY, .setZ method much better.
            geom.get().setX(point1.x())
            geom.get().setY(point1.y())
            geom.get().setZ(point1.z())
            feature.setGeometry(geom)

            layer.updateFeature(feature)
            print('feature '+feature['SUMPDIST'])
            print(str(point1.z()))
            print(str(feature.geometry().get().z()))

            break
layer.commitChanges()
print(str(feature.geometry().get().z()))
```

Comment: When I create a point with QgsPoint things work fine.  point1.x()
26141648.01
point1
<QgsPoint: PointZ (26141648.01000000163912773 642064.88000000000465661 767.87999999999999545)>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to access the underlying QgsPoint object. Think of QgsGeometry as a "container" which holds a point, line, polygon, etc. To do this you call ".get()" on the QgsGeometry.

I.e.

```
geom.get().x()
geom.get().z()
geom.get().setZ(5)
```

Etc

Comment: FANTASTIC!!!  It works like a charm.   Thank you ndawson. :)